# Excel-Changing pictures automatically using cell value in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to automatically insert a picture in cell `AH32` depending on value in `AB32`.

I am able to insert the picture but not depending on the value in `AB32`. How do I fix this please?

Code:

```
Sub Picture()

   Range("AH32").Select

   Dim picname As String

   If Range("AB32").Value < 85# Then

        picname = "C:\Users\20149308\Desktop\sucess\images" & ".png" 'Link to the Picture
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(picname).Select

        With Selection

            .Left = Range("AH32").Left
            .Top = Range("AH32").Top
            .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .ShapeRange.Height = 80#
            .ShapeRange.Width = 80#
            .ShapeRange.Rotation = 0#

        End With

    ElseIf Range("AB32").Value >= 85# Then

        picname = "C:\Users\20149308\Desktop\sucess\succ" & ".jpg"  'Link to the Picture
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(picname).Select

        With Selection

            .Left = Range("AH32").Left
            .Top = Range("AH32").Top
            .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .ShapeRange.Height = 80#
            .ShapeRange.Width = 80#
            .ShapeRange.Rotation = 0#

        End With

    End If

    Range("AH32").Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub

ErrNoPhoto:
    MsgBox "Unable to Find Photo" 'Shows message box if picture not found
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of writing it in a more condensed form with some basic error checking.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Picture()

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   Dim testRange As Range
   Dim picname As String

   Set testRange = ActiveSheet.Range("AB32") 

   If IsEmpty(testRange) Then
       MsgBox "No value in cell AB32"
       Exit Sub
   End If

   Select Case True

        Case Not IsNumeric(testRange.Value2)

            MsgBox "Value in cell AB32 is not numeric"
            Exit Sub

        Case testRange.Value2 < 85#

            picname = "C:\Users\20149308\Desktop\sucess\images" & ".png"

        Case testRange.Value2 >= 85#

            picname = "C:\Users\20149308\Desktop\sucess\succ" & ".jpg"

    End Select

    On Error GoTo ErrNoPhoto

    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(picname).Select

    With Selection

        .Left = Range("AH32").Left
        .Top = Range("AH32").Top
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .ShapeRange.Height = 80#
        .ShapeRange.Width = 80#
        .ShapeRange.Rotation = 0#

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub

ErrNoPhoto:
    MsgBox "Unable to Find Photo" 'Shows message box if picture not found
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without any VBA using the `Camera`.  You can find this by selecting *File* followed by *Options* and *Customize Ribbon* and adding the camera icon to your ribbon.

- Create a blank worksheet and adjust the column width/row height so each of your pictures will sit within the boundaries of a cell (in my example I'm using B2 and B4).
- Select one of these cells and click the `camera` icon to take a photo of it.
- Switch to your reporting sheet and click on it to paste the photo you just took.  You'll see a picture of the cell you originally clicked on within a picture frame that you can rotate and resize.
- Paste your two pictures into the cells on the blank worksheet.  The picture frame on the reporting sheet will now display whichever picture is in the cell you clicked on.
- Create a named range using this formula (adjust sheet names to suit):
  `=IF(Sheet1!$AB$32<85,Sheet2!$B$2,Sheet2!$B$4)` - absolute referencing is important here.
  I called the range `DisplayImage`.
- Select the picture frame and change the formula in the formula bar to `=DisplayImage`.
- The image will now update based on the value in cell `AB32`.